# Use SSRS 2012 to insert into oracle database table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sql-insert, ssrs-2012, insert-update

Currently I have a stored procedure used to populate and update an SSRS report. The report is able to change the country and region that is assigned to the test code using the below scripts :

```
IF sNewRegion is not null THEN
       update  epncdb01.epa set EPA_REGION = sNewRegion
       where   EPA_CDE =  psTstCde;
    ELSE
       update  epncdb01.epa set EPA_REGION = psNewRegion2
       where   EPA_CDE =  psTstCde and EPA_REGION != psNewRegion2;
    END IF;
    --
    IF sNewCntry is not null THEN
       update  epncdb01.epa set EPA_COUNTRY = sNewCntry
       where   EPA_CDE =  psTstCde;
    ELSE
       update  epncdb01.epa set EPA_COUNTRY = psNewCntry2
       where   EPA_CDE =  psTstCde and EPA_COUNTRY != psNewCntry2;
    END IF;
```

But now I need the business user to be able to insert new test codes into the database (current parameter in SSRS for this is psTstCde) I tried the below but it does not work :

```
         IF sNewCode is not null THEN
         insert into epncdb01.epa (EPA_CDE, EPA_REGION, EPA_NAME, EPA_COUNTRY, EPN_NETWORK)
          VALUES(sNewCode, 'NA','NA','NA', 'NA');
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
```

The variables/parameters I created are :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE        P_EPA_CODE_REGION_COUNTRY( 
    psTstCde           IN   VARCHAR2,
    psTstCde2       IN VARCHAR2,
    psNewRegion    IN   VARCHAR2,
    psNewRegion2   IN   VARCHAR2,
    psNewCntry        IN   VARCHAR2,
    psNewCntry2       IN   VARCHAR2,
    curRef             OUT  SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
AS
    sErr               VARCHAR2(200);
    sNewRegion     VARCHAR2(200);
    sNewCntry        VARCHAR2(200);
    sNewCode        VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN   
    sNewRegion := trim(psNewRegion);
    sNewCntry     := trim(psNewCntry);
    sNewCode    :=trim(pststcde2);
```

Any ideas ? Thank you so much !

Comment: I didn't get it.. what is the problem here ?

Comment: Sorry the problem is the script for inserting a new test code does not work